# Request for networking book recommendations

Tags: networking

I'm starting a new job soon with a manufacturer and supplier of fibre-optic multiplexers. I'm not expected to be a techie, but can anyone recommend some books on networking (not necessarily just optical) that would give me a good foundation. My current networking knowledge is minimal.

Comment: Apologies, but one of the reasons I first found SO was looking for recommendations for books on PHP; it was v useful. I've ticked the below answer so you can remove this question if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a basic introduction to the internet and the full-stack of technologies... Take a look at Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633469) or Doug Comer's [Internetworking with TCP/IP, Vol I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131876716).  You should be able to find either one in your public library...

For cabling and network technician's books:

- Comprehensive cabling info: Oliviero and Woodward's [Cabling: The Complete Guide to Copper and Fiber-Optic Networking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470477075)
- In-depth coverage of ethernet (80% of what you'll probably be cabling): Spurgeon's [Ethernet: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926609)
- Advanced troubleshooting (including some protocol troubleshooting): Neal Allen's [Network Maintenance and Troubleshooting Guide: Field Tested Solutions for Everyday Problems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321647416)

Comment: Thanks for that, they look interesting & I will probably hunt one down, but I was thinking more of the physical setup of networking?